# Do I need to change my CV when a former school changes affiliations?

Tags: cv, credentials

Some years ago, I studied in a small training center that had a "cooperative arrangement" with a larger university. I earned a graduate certificate bearing the name of the university along with graduate credits and a transcript from the university, but attended courses in the training center. I put these details on my CV:

```
2005        Graduate Certificate in X        <location>, University of X
```

Recently, the training center and university ended their cooperative arrangement and the training center has a new partnership with another university. Do I need to adjust my CV to reflect the change?

Comment: Why would you change? The current change in the training center's affiliation does not change the education you got in the past.

Comment: Actually, if you got the exact same training as in the university (same examinations, same courses,...), maybe    it would not be unethical to suppress the name of the training center on your CV. The exact location of your classroom does not matter! Granted (again) you got the exact same education as at the university... You have a transcript from the university, which means THEY certify that the quality of your education was at the same level than the one they offer on their main campus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best approach is to keep the original CV entry, as this represents the *actual* qualification that you received. However, you might choose to add a note explaining the history, if you think this is likely to be helpful to prospective readers.

I agree that in the case described by @brechmos, where a university has changed its name, providing this information is likely to be useful. It's less clear to me that this is true in the OP's case: it seems (essentially) that the qualification he has used to be accredited by University X, and is now accredited by University Y. It's not clear to me why this would be useful information to someone reading the CV. I guess it might be relevant if the training centre has a high enough profile that people now naturally associate it with University Y, and would think that something listed with University X must be a different centre. Otherwise, I suspect noting the change is more likely to confuse people than help them...

Comment: This is correct: your CV should reflect the actual degrees received, from the institutions that awarded them. The clarification would be needed if the institute change is not recent, and would thus have fallen out of memory.

Comment: To add to this: I'd even think it possibly detrimental to your application if the institution on the copies of the degree certificates you hand in seem to differ from those on the CV.

Answer (score 5):

Funny, this just happened to me!

On my CV/resume I now have the title of the section as":

*Masters of Science, University of XXXXX (now called XXXX University)*

My degree *is* from "University of XXXX" and so I feel that should go first.  BUT, it would be a good idea to acknowledge the name change, as people will get confused, and so I added it as a parenthetical comment.

Comment: This applies to a name change, but would be misleading in the case of a change of affiliation (as in the OP's case)

Comment: True.  I would still leave the original affiliation as that was the case while the OP was there.  A note below on the CV might be helpful to say the affiliation ended - that way it is clear (and if someone is Google'ing around they aren't going to get confused).

Comment: I would be *so* temped to use "née" even though it does not quite fit...

Answer (score 1):

To use the example provided by brechmos.

> Master of Science, XXXX University (formerly University of XXXXX)

Have used this alternative in my cv.

Answer (score 0):

```
2005   Graduate Certificate in X   <location>, at that time affiliated with University of Y
```

Comment: This answer does not look right. My understanding is that the training center was affiliated with University of X at that time. Also, the OP is asking  if he needs to adjust his CV, you did not address his question.

Comment: @scaaahu The question uses `X` for both the subject studied and the affiliated university; I've used `X` for the subject and `Y` for the university. No material difference.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to what reasoning is behind the answer.

Comment: @StrongBad What part needs explaining?

Comment: Umm, the whole thing. It is not that big of an answer. You leave out the research center name and do not list the new university name. Why is that? As it stands, the answer feels like a comment.

Comment: @StrongBad I'd assumed that "location" (copy-pasted from the question) included the name of the centre. It seems unlikely that the asker's current CV includes only the name of the city, and not the institution, doesn't it? And how is the new university's name relevant? If your PhD advisor had moved to a different university after you graduated, would you put "PhD at X university, advisor Prof Y (now at Z university)"?